# Having trouble calling another class that reads a txt file into an array that is sorted in the program(band operand error)

Tags: java, arrays, class, sorting, operands

so I have a program that takes a txt file and is read in and uses the class of another java file to set up the array. I am trying use selection sort to sort the values placed into the array but it gives me bad operand types for the line: (if array[j] < array[min]). The text file used is:"Country"   "Total CO2 2005 (million tonnes)"   "Road CO2 (million tonnes)" "Road CO2 per person (tonnes)"  "Cars per 1000 people"
10
USA 5951.13 1530.3  5.16    777
UK  2573.4  119.68  1.99    470
Italy   476.08  116.86  2   592
Germany 841.78  150.21  1.82    550
Canada  553.02  123.42  3.82    562
France  414.03  128.13  2.04    477
Russia  1575.44 114.69  0.8 178
Japan   1254.47 224.24  1.76    447
China   5100.6  228.02  0.3 17
India   1147.46 91.06   0.1 8

The program with the class being called carbonDioxide.java:

```
public class CarbonDioxideData {

    private String country;

    private double totalCO2;

    private double roadCO2;

    private double CO2PerPerson;

    private int carsPerPerson;

    public CarbonDioxideData() {
        country = "blank_country";
        totalCO2 = -1.0;
        roadCO2 = -1.0;
        CO2PerPerson = -1.0;
        carsPerPerson = -1; 
    }

    public String toString() {
        String result = country;

        result += " " + totalCO2;
        result += " " + roadCO2;
        result += " " + CO2PerPerson;
        result += " " + carsPerPerson;

        return result;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public double getTotalCO2() {
        return totalCO2;
    }

    public void setTotalCO2(double totalCO2) {
        this.totalCO2 = totalCO2;
    }

    public double getRoadCO2() {
        return roadCO2;
    }

    public void setRoadCO2(double roadCO2) {
        this.roadCO2 = roadCO2;
    }

    public double getCO2PerPerson() {
        return CO2PerPerson;
    }

    public void setCO2PerPerson(double cO2PerPerson) {
        CO2PerPerson = cO2PerPerson;
    }

    public int getCarsPerPerson() {
        return carsPerPerson;
    }

    public void setCarsPerPerson(int carsPerPerson) {
        this.carsPerPerson = carsPerPerson;
    }
}
```

The program I am writing calling the two above, CarbonAnalysis.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CarbonAnalysis {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        //CarbonDioxideData c1 = new CarbonDioxideData();
        //c1.setCountry("canada");
        //System.out.println(c1);
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fileName ="";
        File inputFile = null;
        Scanner fileReader = null;
        while(fileReader==null){
        try{
        System.out.println("Enter input file name:");
        fileName= userInput.next();
        inputFile = new File(fileName);
        fileReader = new Scanner(inputFile);
        System.out.println("Successfully opening " + fileName);
        }catch(IOException err){
            System.out.println("Something went wrong");
            System.out.println(err);
            System.out.println("Please retry");
        }
        }

        String testLine = fileReader.nextLine();
        System.out.println(testLine);

        int numberOfEntries = fileReader.nextInt();
        System.out.println(numberOfEntries);

        CarbonDioxideData[] array = new CarbonDioxideData[numberOfEntries];
        for(int i =0;i<numberOfEntries;i++){


        CarbonDioxideData c1 = new CarbonDioxideData();
        String country = fileReader.next();
        c1.setCountry(country);
        double totalCO2 = fileReader.nextDouble();
        c1.setTotalCO2(totalCO2);
        double roadCO2 = fileReader.nextDouble();
        c1.setRoadCO2(roadCO2);
        double perPerson = fileReader.nextDouble();
        c1.setCO2PerPerson(perPerson);
        int cars = fileReader.nextInt();
        c1.setCarsPerPerson(cars);
        //System.out.println(c1);
        array[i]=c1;
    }
    printArray(array);
    emissionStats(array);
    }

    public static void printArray(CarbonDioxideData[] a){
        for(int i=0; i<a.length;i++){
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void emissionStats(CarbonDioxideData[] array){
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) { 
 // find index of smallest remaining value 
            int min = i; 
            for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) { 


                if (array[j] < array[min]) { 
                min = j; 
                } 
            } 

 // swap smallest value its proper place, a[i] 
            swap(array, i, min); 
        } 

    }

    public static void swap(CarbonDioxideData[] a, int i, int j) { 
        if (i != j) { 
            CarbonDioxideData temp = a[i]; 
            a[i] = a[j]; 
            a[j] = temp; 
        } 
    }    
}
```

The error I am receiving when compiling: 
CarbonAnalysis.java:68: error: bad operand types for binary operator '<'
if array[j] < array[min]

first type: CarbonDioxideData
Second type: CarbondDioxidedata

I am at a loss I have no  idea how to get it to work. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`<` , `>` binary operators can be used with primitive types.

```
public class CarbonDioxideData implements Comparable<CarbonDioxideData> {

   private String country;

   private double totalCO2;

   private double roadCO2;

   private double CO2PerPerson;

   private int carsPerPerson;


   @Override
   public int compareTo(CarbonDioxideData that) {
    final int BEFORE = -1;
    final int EQUAL = 0;
    final int AFTER = 1;


    if (this == that) return EQUAL;

        //Compare function according to your logic
    if (this.totalCO2 == that.totalCO2) return EQUAL;
    if (this.totalCO2 > that.totalCO2) 
            return AFTER;
    else 
            return BEFORE;
  }

}
```

Your comparison should be as

```
if (array[j].compareTo(array[min]) < 0) { 
    min = j; 
}
```

Comment: @user3497212 just a reminder, you should accept the answer by clicking check icon.